# AttributeError: Module 'Users' Has No Method 'Main'

Tags: python, brownie

In Brownie I'm running a script which sends me this error "AttributeError: Module 'Users' Has No Method 'Main'. Do you have any suggestions on how I can fix this?

```
import os
from brownie import network, accounts, config, Hello

def main():
    my_account = accounts.add(os.getenv(config['wallets']['from_key']))
    hello = Hello.deploy({'from': my_account})
    print(hello.address)
```

This is what I receive when I run the deploy.py script:

````
Brian Lee@MSI MINGW64 ~/Python39/brownie/New folder
$ brownie run scripts/deploy.py --network kovan
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
Brownie v1.14.3 - Python development framework for Ethereum

NewFolderProject is the active project.
  File "c:\users\brian, line line, in in
    return_value, frame = run(
  File "c:\users\brian, line line, in in
    raise AttributeError(f"Module '{name}' has no method '{method_name}'")
AttributeError: Module 'Users.Brian Lee.Python39.brownie.New folder.scripts.deploy' has no method 'main'```
````

Comment: Do you have the whole stack trace? The error doesn't seems to be from the code in the question.

Comment: Hi @Ismael , thanks for the response. I just updated what occurs when I run the deploy.py script. Does that help?

Comment: Is deploy.py inside script/ folder? Try running `brownie run deploy.py --network kovan`.

Comment: @Ismael , I double checked and yes deploy.py is saved under the script/folder.

Comment: Try saving your work before running the scripts

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem on MacOSX. I have tried to save all the scripts and recompile all the sources but this problem still exists.

Interestingly, I noticed that the questioner uses `def main():` to package all the code in the python file, while I am still using the old-styled method like
`if __name__ == '__main__':` (my Python version 3.8.5)

Is this the key point that would trigger this error?

**update**

Today I changed all the `if __name__ == '__main__':` code in my python files into new version of `def main():` and it works. Case closed. Thanks.

**related docs**

From Brownie's doc file I find the definition of function `scripts.run.py` [here](https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api-project.html?highlight=run.py#scripts.run). It says this function has a parameter called 'method_name' which has been set to "main" by default. This means you must define a "main" function otherwise this run.py will not be correctly compiled.

Answer (score 0):

I was resolved this issue by @user91379 answer.Edit any script ,for example:deploy.py. This will trigger Brownie recompile all source, this problem will disappear.Thanks for user91379.

Answer (score 0):

I saved the dep.py before running `brownie run scripts/dep.py`
and that worked.